# Address casting in C

Tags: c, hardware

Question related to little endian and big endian:

```
unsigned int i = 0x12345678; // assuming int is 4 bytes.
unsigned char* pc = &i;
```

Now, if *pc is 12 that means it is BIG ENDIAN because lowest address is storing MSB and if 78 Little. Is my understanding correct?

If yes, then my question is, why pc will get the lowest address of i? How does it works? Also, how many memory addresses will be needed to store i?

Assume a 32 bit Architecture

Comment: Is this 16, 32 or 64 bit architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any variable will be identified by a single address, regardless of the size of the type.

If `int i` is stored at address `0x1f00`, it takes up the four bytes `0x1f00`, `0x1f01`, `0x1f02` and `0x1f03` of space. Still, when you create a reference to it, you will get the start address only, because the size is implied by the type.

So when you create a reference to an `int` and cast it to a `char` reference, you don't change the address, you simply tell the compiler to treat it as a `char` instead. I.e. the address is still `0x1f00`, and when you dereference it you will read whatever is stored there, which is like you say MSB for little endian and LSB for big endian machines.

Comment: Wow, I never thought like that. Thanks! so, how did you decide that each byte will be given a unique address, why not two byte one address?

Comment: Each byte in memory has an individual address. But as I said, when you create a reference (pointer) you get the start address.

Comment: Okay, this concept of "each byte with unique address" holds true irrespective of the architecture 16/32/64. Right?

Comment: A byte is the basic unit of memory in all modern architectures that I know about. 64/32/16-bit register/address size is irrelevant.

Comment: @user2901020 One thing to add -- pointers *can* refer to any single byte in memory but operations are usually performed on architecture-sized chunks. For example reading something from memory means copying it from RAM memory to the processor cache or to a processor register. Copying occupies the entire `memory bus` (which is architecture-sized). So in 64bit architectures reading a double (8bytes), an int (4bytes) or a char (1byte) would imply an equal transfer cost from memory to the processor.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes; your understanding is correct.
2. Because that is the way C works, and because it makes sense. The address of `i` is the starting byte followed by 3 other bytes (in the 32-bit architecture). That is, given the starting address and the size, the bytes where the value is stored is `&i+0`, `&i+1`, `&i+2` and `&i+3` (rather than `&i-0`, `&i-1`, `&i-2` and `&i-3` which you seem to think might make some sense).

For most practical purposes, it really makes very little difference, so it really isn't something to sweat over.  As long as the hardware is self-consistent, all works OK.  There were (still are) some chips that could be switched from big-endian to little-endian at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 0X01234567; // int occupies 4 bytes
            Address in the increasing order
        --------------------------------------->
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 0013FF59 | 0013FF60  | 0013FF61  |0013FF62  | 0013FF63 |
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|          |   67      |   45      |   23     |    01    |
+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+----------+

why pc will get the lowest address of i? How does it works?
```

when you say

```
unsigned char* pc = &i;
```

`pc` gets the lowest address. and when you say `int j = *pc`, the system knows, `int` occupies 4 bytes and it is `little endian`. It knows how to get the number from the address stored in `pc`.

```
Also, how many memory addresses will be needed to store i?
```

On your system 4 memory locations are need to store i. And the access i, 1 memory address is enough.